# Update router firmware without using web interface

Tags: router, firmware, d-link

I have a `D-Link DSL-2740EL` wireless router. How can I update router's firmware without using web interface?

Assume router's firmware is corrupted. So I can't log in to my router. Then how can I update the firmware?

Is there any other method to update the firmware without using web interface?

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

> 1. Plug the Ethernet cable that connects your computer, that was plugged into one of the LAN ports,
> 2. Setup your PC with static IP - ex: 192.168.0.2 (different from 192.168.0.1)
> 3. Make sure the PC has the new firmware
> 4. Unplug the power
> 5. Hold the reset button for 3~5 seconds and re plug the power WITHOUT RELEASING THE RESET BUTTON.
> 6. Wait until the power LED turns solid red (after about 30 seconds)
> 7. Open a web browser to 192.168.0.1 and then you should see EMERGENCY FLASHING page then click browse/upload locate the file and click
>      UPLOAD FIRMWARE NOW
> 8. You should see a SUCCSESS page, If you don’t then re do steps 2-6

References: [dlink forum](http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=44909.0), [OpenWRT hardware wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dsl-2740b)

Comment: not worked for me.